# How do I aggregate data off of a google search

Tags: search, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate movie times off of google/movies search into a usable format such as json or xml

http://www.google.com/movies?q=movie+times&sc=1&mid=&hl=en&oi=showtimes&ct=change-location&near=new+york

The Google AJAX api does not seem to work for this as you cannot do a movie search.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Not really an answer, but if everything else fails, you can always do screen-scraping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the technique called [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Basically, you have to fetch the results page using some server-side scripting, and then extract data from it, to present in a formated way (json, xml, etc). Regular expressions or a DOM/XML parser could help.

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://www.mzzt.net/2009/01/14/opensearch-google-in-windows-7/) has a PHP script that converts Google results to RSS.